# Блок Яндекс "поделиться" - как создать несколько на одной странице?

Tags: javascript, ya-share2

Как создать несколько блоков Яндекс "поделиться" на одной странице, что бы делиться разным контентом?

Сайт на бутстрапе, CMS пока нет - все правится ручками.

Comment: Используйте API https://tech.yandex.ru/share/doc/dg/api-docpage/

Answer (score 2):

Создайте несколько блоков с разными `data-url`:

```
<div class="ya-share2" data-url="example.com/1" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin"></div>
<div class="ya-share2" data-url="example.com/2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook,gplus,linkedin"></div>
```